# Render as PDF: Landscape orientation not working

Tags: visualforce

I've been looking everywhere and trying lots of things (going back to version 28 and older, using doctype="html-5.0" and more.), and I can't seem to get the landscape orientation to trigger when rendering as a PDF.

What am I doing wrong?  (somewhat Redacted).  Any help is appreciated!!

```
<apex:page standardController="Appeal_Review__c" extensions="EXTENSION1, EXTENSION2" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<!-- <Apex:pageblock title="Export Results"> -->
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            @page {

            size: landscape;
            margin: 25mm;
            @top-center {
            content: "Sample";
            }
            @bottom-center {
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
            }
            }
            .page-break {
            display:block;
            page-break-after:always;
            }
            body {
            font-family: Arial Unicode MS;-->
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style ="page-break-before:always">
            <table width = "100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" height="30" valigh="center"><b><i> Search Results </i></b></td></tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" height="10"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
            <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <th align="center" width="10%">column 1</th>
                    <th align="center" width="10%">2</th>
                    <th align="center" width="50%">3</th>
                    <th align="center" width="30%">4</th>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!VARIABLE}" var="c">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">{!c.SOMETHING}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </table>                                      
        </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use below code snippet

```
 <style>
            @page {  
                     size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */  
                     margin: 5mm; 
                  } 
            @page:first {  
                     size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */ 
                     margin: 5mm; 
                     margin-top: 3mm; 

                  }  
</style>
```

Comment: Oh that works great - though only for the first page.  The other pages are not in landscape.  How would you apply landscape for all PDF pages?

Comment: it would work for all pages as well. try with removing second styling then it will be applied for all pages.

Comment: oops, nevermind, I had a typo in there.  Works great, thank you!